# XML to JSON in specific format

Tags: php, json, xml

I have a XML file that I need to parse to specific JSON format.

Since my XML is "id based" file - meaning it uses id numbers for many elements, and I need names instead of id's in JSON my approach was to:

1. load XML in PHP
2. get proper names of elements instead of id's used by XML
3. put results into array
4. json_encode that array with JSON_FORCE_OBJECT

After doing it I'm getting json in this format:

```
{
  "0": {
    "sports": {
      "0": {
        "name": "Baseball",
        "tournaments": {
          "0": {
            "name": "South Korea",
            "leagues": {
              "0": {
                "name": "KBO League",
                "matches": {
                  "0": {
                    "home_team": "Doosan Bears",
                    "away_team": "Kiwoom Heroes",
                    "date": "2021-05-13 11:30:00",
                    "markets": {
                      "0": {
                        "name": "Final 12",
                        "odds": {
                          "1": "1.74",
                          "2": "2.10"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "1": {
    "sports": {
      "0": {
        "name": "Baseball",
        "tournaments": {
          "0": {
            "name": "South Korea",
            "leagues": {
              "0": {
                "name": "KBO League",
                "matches": {
                  "0": {
                    "home_team": "Doosan Bears",
                    "away_team": "Kiwoom Heroes",
                    "date": "2021-05-13 11:30:00",
                    "markets": {
                      "0": {
                        "name": "Final 12",
                        "odds": {
                          "1": "1.70",
                          "2": "2.03"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

but it should look like this:

```
 {
  "0": {
    "sports": {
      "0": {
        "name": "Baseball",
        "tournaments": {
          "0": {
            "name": "South Korea",
            "leagues": {
              "0": {
                "name": "KBO League",
                "matches": {
                  "0": {
                    "home_team": "Doosan Bears",
                    "away_team": "Kiwoom Heroes",
                    "date": "2021-05-13 11:30:00",
                    "markets": {
                      "0": {
                        "name": "Final 12",
                        "odds": {
                          "1": "1.74",
                          "2": "2.10"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
                "matches": {
                  "1": {
                    "home_team": "Doosan Bears",
                    "away_team": "Kiwoom Heroes",
                    "date": "2021-05-13 11:30:00",
                    "markets": {
                      "0": {
                        "name": "Final 12",
                        "odds": {
                          "1": "1.70",
                          "2": "2.03"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

That's how I'm doing it in PHP.
After loading all necessary data into parameters for each element in XML I'm creating a new object like this:

```
$match_to_array[] = array (
    'sports' => 
        array (
            array (
                'name' => $sport_name,
                'tournaments' => 
                array (
                    array (
                        'name' => $tournament_name,
                        'leagues' => 
                        array (
                            array (
                                'name' => $league_name,
                                'matches' => 
                                array (
                                    array (
                                        'home_team' => $hometeam_name,
                                        'away_team' => $awayteam_name,
                                        'date' => $full_date_of_match,
                                        'markets' => 
                                        array (
                                            array (
                                                'name' => $market,
                                                'odds' => 
                                                array (
                                                    '1' => $odd_1,
                                                    'X' => $odd_x,
                                                    '2' => $odd_2,
                                                ),
                                            ),
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
```

then I'm adding that element into the final array that I want do encode, like this:

```
array_push($matches_in_array, $match_to_array);
```

and after looping through whole XML file, I'm encoding this big array, like this:

```
$json = json_encode($matches_in_array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
var_dump($json);
```

Using that code, looks like each element has key "0", instead of proper one. By proper one, I mean keys that will represents number of sports, tournament, leagues and matches.

Comment: _"...but it should look like this"_ - are you sure? You have two identical indices (matches) at the same level, meaning the second one will overwrite the first one.

Comment: well U R half right, I mean it's the same match, so it should overright, but all the matches I have looks the same, so they are not group by league, then tournament and sport. Looks like each match it's a separated object.